# Unix: find files in every subdirectory named upd

Tags: unix, find

I have directory tree structure which looks like this

```
/app/bad/upd /app/pass/upd /app/bad/upd /app/warn/upd
```

I want to build a find command which can list all the files in every sub-directory named upd.

Currently I list it individually

```
find /app/bad/upd -type f -name "*${FILE_NAME}*"
```

Comment: Flagged as off-topic, this belongs on SuperUser or Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you look for:

```
find /app -type d -name upd -exec ls -l {} +
```

or perhaps:

```
find /tmp/* -type d -name upd -exec sh -c "ls -l {}/*${FILE_NAME}* 2>/dev/null" sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `upd` directory is always in the 2nd directory down, you could simply do:

```
ls /app/*/upd
```